# jQuery loading message on iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following code that loads pages into an iframe on all the href clicks. However, some of the pages can take a few seconds to load so I want to show a loading icon with the iframe element greyed out until the content has loaded and then hide the loading element. I've used ajaxStart and ajaxStop functions in the past which work well, but seeing as the pages are not being called by Ajax I dont think that will work. Can anyone suggest how this can be done?

```
<iframe src="/dashboard" name="contentFrame" id="contentFrame"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#contentFrame").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of ajaxStart  you may show the **show a loading icon** before changing the iframe src attribute:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // show your icon here
      $("#contentFrame").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
})
```

And, instead of ajaxStop  you can use the [load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load):

```
$("#contentFrame").on('load', function(e) {
    // remove your icon here
})
```